# ObservableCollection in Secondwindow

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

i have two Windows.
In Windows 1 i prepare an ObservableCollection.
In Windows 2 i want bind this to a listview.

They are both in the same namespace.

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
   public ObservableCollection<KeyListItem> keys;

   public Window1 {
     this.keys = new ObservableCollection<KeyListItem>();

... some code i create the items (key) ...
keys.Add(key);
   }

private void OpenDialogAndShowList() {
//this i start from a button

var sKeys = new Window2();
sKeys.lvSelectKey.ItemsSource = keys;
}
}
```

In Window2 the XAML looks like this:

```
<Grid>
        <ListView Name="lvSelectKey" ItemsSource="{Binding keys}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="211" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="564">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="Id" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Id}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="Algorithm" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Algorithm}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="Bits" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Bits}" />
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>


    </Grid>
```

The Problem is:

i see some empty lines in my listview.
When i add three items, i see three lines ..... and so on.

But i don`t see any content.

When i debug it, i see the OC is not empty.

Somebody see my failure? :)

Comment: First, remove the "ItemSource" attribute from the Windows XAML: you already set the property in the C# section. Then, how is defined the "KeyListItem" object?

Comment: public class KeyListItem
    {
        public int Id;
        public string Name;
        public string Algorithm;
        public int Bits;
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should adjust the class as follows:

```
public class KeyListItem
{ 
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string Algorithm { get; set; }
  public int Bits { get; set; }
}
```

That is use properties instead of simple fields: the binding engine works only on properties.

Answer (score 0):

I got it, thank you Mario.
I forgot the get; set;

```
public class KeyListItem
{
    public int Id { get; set;}
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Algorithm { get; set; }
    public int Bits { get; set; }
}
```